# What does this line of code mean

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

There is lots of changes in C++ 11 and afterwards. And I just came across this line of code, I thought I created an empty array which defaults to zero and I just added an element in the beginning of the array which is 99. But it prints 42. I am really confused.

```
int a1 []{};
a1[0] = 99;
cout<<"a1 is " << a1[0];
```

Console:

```
a1 is 42
```

Comment: `int a1 []{};` is not a valid declaration in C++. The code is invalid. If you managed to compile and run it, direct the question to your compiler's authors (or at least specify here which compiler you used). In any case, this has nothing to do with C++ language, C++11 or not.

Comment: Undefined behaviour yields undefined results.

Comment: The only thing C++11-ish is the absence of `=` in `int a1 []{};`. Everything else, including the illegal/vendor-specific part, has been the case before C++11.

Comment: I'd really like to know why UB prints out the meaning of life, though.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not standard C++ program. Zero size arrays are not allowed in C & C++. You should use `-pedantic-errors` command line option if you are using `g++` & `clang++` compiler to strictly confirm to the standard & disable any compiler extensions.

See live demo [here](http://rextester.com/HGL71077). `Clang++` says

```
source_file.cpp:7:14: error: zero size arrays are an extension [-Werror,-Wzero-length-array]
    int a1 []{};
             ^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you compile that code with `g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -W -Wall`, you will get an error:

```
test.cpp:6:12: error: zero-size array ‘a1’
  int a1 []{};
```

This code is invalid.

As an extension, some compilers offer (in a less compliant mode) zero sized arrays. In which case, you simply read/wrote the byte adjacent to the empty array, which just so happened to not crash...